# How do I set JavaScript's scope to partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views

I have an ASP.NET partial view

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="remove-item"></div>        
    <input name="Account" class="currency" />
     ...some more html input elements removed for brevity
</div>
```

The partial view has its own JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $(".remove-item").click(function(){
          var i =  $("input.currency");
          // do something
       })   


    })
</script>
```

On a page, this partial view appears multiple time. Each `input` element will have unique name. However JavaScript is selecting elements using class name.

Issue is when second instance of partial view renders, `$(".remove-item")` will select element from the first partial view as well.  Because it scans the whole DOM.

What is the best way to scope JavaScript here so that it only selects elements with its own scope?

---

only selecting elements

Comment: FYI, putting JavaScript in each partial view is going to slow down your initial render. The HTML parser has to switch to the JS engine, load & parse & run the JS, then switch back to the HTML parser every time it comes to a `<script>` tag. If the code is always the same (i.e., you don't write server-side code into each script), just put it in an external file and load it once.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with an unknown amount of repeating elements, you can use **event delegation**. Instead of outputting the JS multiple times and having an event listener on each partial, output it once and have only 1 event for the whole set of partials. No matter how many elements end up on the page, even if more show up dynamically, your events will still fire:

1. Output this JavaScript only once:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".containing-parent").on('click', '.remove-item', function() {
        var i = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('input.currency');
    });
</script>
```

2. Wrap your partials with a div that can have the one event attached to it:

```
<div class="containing-parent">
    ...partials go here
</div>
```

You will need to make sure your javascript can find the `div.containing-parent` when it executes.

## Example:

```js
$(".containing-parent").on('click', '.remove-item', function() {
  var i = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('input.currency').val();
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containing-parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="remove-item">X</div>
    <input name="Account1" class="currency" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="remove-item">X</div>
    <input name="Account2" class="currency" value="2" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="remove-item">X</div>
    <input name="Account3" class="currency" value="3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I do not use jquery but it looks clean.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is creating a Module.

```js
// Module

function PartialView(root) {
  var button = root.querySelector('button');
  
  button.addEventListener('click', remove);
  
  
  function remove() {
    button.removeEventListener('click', remove);
    root.remove();
  }
  
}

// Attaching listeners

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.partial-view'))
  .forEach(PartialView);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="partial-view">
    <button>remove</button>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="partial-view">
    <button>remove</button>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="partial-view">
    <button>remove</button>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="partial-view">
    <button>remove</button>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="partial-view">
    <button>remove</button>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not a module; that's a closure, or an object. [Modules](https://javascript.info/modules-intro) are a specific thing in JavaScript.

Comment: How `root` is getting passed and whats the value of `root` parameter?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I see what you mean, what I have implemented is a design pattern called the revealing module pattern

Comment: @LP13 the forEach uses PartialView as callback and it is responsible for injecting it.

Comment: Actually, the RMP would return the object built within the outer function, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the div that contain the partial view a Unique ID

```
<div class="wrapper" id="partialViewHandler">
```

Then on your Javascript first find the ContainerDiv and store the value inside a parameter and use it inside your JQuery selectors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = $("#partialViewHandler");
    $(function () {
        $(".remove-item", x).click(function () {
            var i = $("input.currency", x);
            // do something
        })
    })
</script>
```